# how to set the cuda path in the conda environment?

Tags: anaconda, cuda, virtualenv, conda

I am using ubuntu 22 LTS. I want to use a different version of Cuda in the conda virtual environment. I want to use a virtual conda environment for tensorflow 1.x and another conda env for tensorflow 2.x and one environment for PyTorch. I add the version of Cuda when I created the environment. My problem is that instead of using the Cuda that is installed in the conda env (ie. `conda create -n tf1 cudnn=7.6.5 cudatoolkit=10.1.243`), it uses the system cuda. when I type the

```
nvcc --version
```

the output is:

> ```
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
> Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
> Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
> ```

how can I set the path to use the specific Cuda version installed in the environment and not the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the CUDA_HOME environment variable with this command.

```
conda env config vars set CUDA_HOME=""
```

You should be able to use this command to find the path of your conda-installed CUDA library.

```
sudo find / -name nvcc
```

You might also want to look at this documentation to have environment variables set as part of the activation step.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables

Comment: thank u for your answer. However, I haven't installed cuda-nvcc in the env . I have installed cudatoolkit and cudnn via conda. is there another way to find the path of cuda in the conda env?

Comment: So I just tried this on a fresh instance, and found that I had to install cuda-nvcc as well. I wonder if the issue is that cudatoolkit  and cudnn aren't install cuda-nvcc and thus aren't providing an alternative path when the conda env is activated.

Comment: I believe this is a valid stack overflow question, as there are thousands of like questions on software installation and path. For myself, I found that installing cuda into a Windows conda environment with `conda create` does create and assign `CUDA_PATH` automatically without any configuration, but it does not save this cuda path in the user's environment variables. The necessary path is `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\envname` and has to be saved separately. Note that this path is not specific to cuda nor is it the location of nvcc; instead it points to the entire conda env.